# MySQL Query: Delete from 'table2' where column = 'value' IF column in 'table1' = 'value'

Tags: mysql, delete

I am trying to execute a MySQL query to delete rows from 'table2' where column = 'value' IF column in 'table1' = 'value'

I have 2 tables...

Table 1 is called `accounts`
Table 2 is called `inventoryitems`

The column in question for `accounts` is called `banned`
The column in question for `inventoryitems` is called `itemid`

I would like to `DELETE FROM inventoryitems WHERE itemid = 2340000`
IF...
the column `banned` in `accounts` has a value of `1`

You can join the table `accounts` to `inventoryitems` by a 3rd table called `characters`.

Table `accounts` has columns: `id` (primary key) and `banned`.

Table `characters` has columns: `characterid` and `accountid` (`accountid` links to `id` in table `accounts`).

Table `inventoryitems` has columns `itemid` and `characterid` (`characterid` links to `characterid` in table `characters`)

Hope I have provided enough information...

I have tried:

```
DELETE FROM inventoryitems 
WHERE characterid IN 
    (SELECT characterid 
     from characters 
     WHERE accountid IN 
        (SELECT id 
         from accounts 
         WHERE banned = '1'
        )
    ) 
  AND itemid = '2340000';
```

However this deletes all rows in the `inventoryitems` table where `itemid = '234000'`. Seems to still ignore the check for '1' in `banned` column of accounts table.... I think this is close though...

Here are the SHOW CREATE TABLE queries for the 3 tables:

```
'accounts', 'CREATE TABLE `accounts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(13) NOT NULL default '',
  `password` varchar(128) NOT NULL default '',
  `salt` varchar(32) default NULL,
  `loggedin` tinyint(4) NOT NULL default '0',
  `lastlogin` timestamp NULL default NULL,
  `createdat` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `birthday` date NOT NULL default '0000-00-00',
  `banned` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `banreason` text,
  `gm` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `email` tinytext,
  `emailcode` varchar(40) default NULL,
  `forumaccid` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `macs` tinytext,
  `lastknownip` varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',
  `lastpwemail` timestamp NOT NULL default '2002-12-31 17:00:00',
  `tempban` timestamp NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `greason` tinyint(4) default NULL,
  `paypalNX` int(11) default NULL,
  `mPoints` int(11) default NULL,
  `cardNX` int(11) default NULL,
  `webadmin` int(1) default '0',
  `lastlogininmilliseconds` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `guest` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `donorpoints` tinyint(1) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `forumaccid` (`forumaccid`),
  KEY `ranking1` (`id`,`banned`,`gm`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=753 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'

'characters', 'CREATE TABLE `characters` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `accountid` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `world` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `name` varchar(13) NOT NULL default '',
  `level` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `exp` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `str` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `dex` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `luk` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `int` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `hp` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `mp` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `maxhp` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `maxmp` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `meso` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `hpApUsed` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `mpApUsed` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `job` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `skincolor` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `gender` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `fame` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `hair` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `face` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `ap` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `sp` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `map` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `spawnpoint` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `gm` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `party` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `buddyCapacity` int(11) NOT NULL default '25',
  `createdate` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `rank` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',
  `rankMove` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `jobRank` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',
  `jobRankMove` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `guildid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `guildrank` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '5',
  `messengerid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `messengerposition` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '4',
  `reborns` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `mountlevel` int(9) NOT NULL default '1',
  `mountexp` int(9) NOT NULL default '0',
  `mounttiredness` int(9) NOT NULL default '0',
  `petid` int(10) default '0',
  `married` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `partnerid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `cantalk` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '1',
  `marriagequest` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `omokwins` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `omoklosses` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `omokties` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `matchcardwins` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `matchcardlosses` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `matchcardties` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `MerchantMesos` int(11) default '0',
  `HasMerchant` tinyint(1) default '0',
  `equipslots` int(11) NOT NULL default '48',
  `useslots` int(11) NOT NULL default '48',
  `setupslots` int(11) NOT NULL default '48',
  `etcslots` int(11) NOT NULL default '48',
  `allianceRank` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '5',
  `clan` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '-1',
  `pvpkills` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `pvpdeaths` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `omok` int(4) default NULL,
  `matchcard` int(4) default NULL,
  `zakumlvl` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  `gmtext` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default '0',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  KEY `accountid` (`accountid`),
  KEY `party` (`party`),
  KEY `ranking1` (`level`,`exp`),
  KEY `ranking2` (`gm`,`job`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=30792 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'

'inventoryitems', 'CREATE TABLE `inventoryitems` (
  `inventoryitemid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `characterid` int(11) default NULL,
  `storageid` int(10) unsigned default NULL,
  `itemid` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `inventorytype` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `position` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `quantity` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `owner` tinytext NOT NULL,
  `petid` int(11) NOT NULL default '-1',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`inventoryitemid`),
  KEY `inventoryitems_ibfk_1` (`characterid`),
  KEY `characterid` (`characterid`),
  KEY `inventorytype` (`inventorytype`),
  KEY `storageid` (`storageid`),
  KEY `characterid_2` (`characterid`,`inventorytype`),
  CONSTRAINT `inventoryitems_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`characterid`) REFERENCES `characters` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25799280 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'
```

Comment: I have tried:

DELETE FROM inventoryitems WHERE characterid IN
(SELECT characterid from characters WHERE accountid IN
(SELECT id from accounts WHERE banned = '1'))
AND itemid = '2340000';

However this deletes all rows in the `inventoryitems` table where `itemid` = '234000'. Seems to still ignore the check for '1' in `banned` column of `accounts` table.... I think this is close though...

Comment: The `DELETE` statement seems correct. Can you also tell us the primary keys of `characters` and `inventoryitems`? Also: does the `banned` column have only either `0` or `1` values? Or others, too?

Comment: And a longshot. Does the Delete statement behave differently if you remove the single quotes from this line?: (`WHERE banned = 1`)

Comment: @ypercube, To answer your question better, I have provided a screenshot (I hope this is allowed): http://oi42.tinypic.com/2eochhy.jpg
and ypercube, no it does not behave differently sorry =/, And yes banned column is either 0 or 1.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with *"Seems to still ignore the check for '1' in banned column of accounts table"*? (provide a few rows from the tables and what is the result of the Delete statement)

Comment: Also, the best would be to edit the question and add the output of the `SHOW CREATE TABLE inventoryitems;` (and the same for the other 2 tables.) You may have triggers or something else we can't think of now.

Comment: It would be quite hard for me to provide you with the rows exactly but what I mean is: I know there are accounts where `banned` = `0` and the same account (found by linking it via the character table) does have in `inventoryitems` rows where `itemid` = `234000`. These also get deleted when running the script in the opening post.

Comment: Check: The code uses `characters.characterid` but the image in the link has `characters.id` (and maybe also `characters.characterid` but that is not shown)

Comment: "`gender` int(11) NOT NULL default '0'," says that you are allowing for 2 billion different genders!  Suggest TINYINT that that and many other fields -- saves space, hence speeds up things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement seems to be correct. It could also be written like this:

```
DELETE ii
FROM inventoryitems AS ii 
WHERE ii.itemid = 2340000
  AND EXISTS  
    ( SELECT * 
      FROM characters AS c
      WHERE c.characterid = ii.characterid
        AND EXISTS
            ( SELECT *
              FROM accounts AS a
              WHERE a.id = c.accountid 
                AND a.banned = 1
            )
    ) ;
```

One thing that may be causing this is if you have a character related to many accounts and one of them has `banned = 1` while the other have `banned = 0`. I assume you want the deletion to happen (not with just one but) only if all the related accounts have `banned = 1`. We can modify the above code to:

```
DELETE ii
FROM inventoryitems AS ii 
WHERE ii.itemid = 2340000
  AND EXISTS  
    ( SELECT * 
      FROM characters AS c
      WHERE c.characterid = ii.characterid
        AND EXISTS
            ( SELECT *
              FROM accounts AS a
              WHERE a.id = c.accountid 
                AND a.banned = 1
            )
        AND NOT EXISTS
            ( SELECT *
              FROM accounts AS a
              WHERE a.id = c.accountid 
                AND a.banned = 0
            )
    ) ;
```

or simpler to:

```
DELETE ii
FROM inventoryitems AS ii 
WHERE ii.itemid = 2340000
  AND EXISTS  
    ( SELECT * 
      FROM characters AS c
        JOIN accounts AS a
          ON a.id = c.accountid
      WHERE c.characterid = ii.characterid 
      HAVING MIN(a.banned) = 1
    ) ;
```

---

After the clarifications, all the above are void. The problem was that `characters` table does not have `characterid` column but only `id`. So the statement used by the OP was translated/parsed as:

```
DELETE FROM inventoryitems
WHERE characterid IN 
    (SELECT inventoryitems.characterid         -- notice this
     from characters
     WHERE accountid IN 
        (SELECT id 
         from accounts 
         WHERE banned = '1'
        )
    ) 
  AND itemid = '2340000';
```

which makes the subquery uncorrelated and means "delete all rows with `itemid = 2340000`" if there exists at least one row (any row, not necessarily related) in the accounts with `banned=1`"

That's one reason why it's good to **always** (*) write columns with their full name as `tablename.columnname` or `tablealias.columnname` (an error would have been thrown if you had done this and problem would have been solved faster.)

(*) Unless one wants this behaviour to occur, which is a rather extreme case.

Comment: My statement was incorrect but fixed due to you pointing out the fact that _The code uses characters.characterid but the image in the link has characters.id_

So the correct query is:

`DELETE FROM inventoryitems
WHERE characterid IN
    (SELECT id
     from characters
     WHERE accountid IN 
        (SELECT id 
         from accounts 
         WHERE banned = '1'
        )
    ) 
  AND itemid = '2340000';`

Change your answer to this and I will mark it as _Answered!_ Thank you very much. PS. Your above scripts did not work and returned errors _Unknown column 'c.characterid' in 'where clause'_

Comment: Yeah, if I was the one that made the initial database set up I definitely would have written the columns as you have mentioned. However the java source code for which this database is used for would need a major overhaul! Thanks again! I have learnt a lot from this.

Comment: You could also use the "multi-table delete" syntax.  It might run faster than EXISTS.  (It might need LEFT JOIN.)

Comment: @RickJames, the question was not about efficiency.